# How to do MAX(COUNT(*)) in sql

Tags: mysql, count, max

i've two table :

```
prgm[id,name]
notes[id,note,id_prgm]
```

I actually have a request to know some info about prgm :

```
SELECT p.id, name, AVG(note), COUNT(note)
FROM notes n
    JOIN prgm p
    ON p.id=n.id_prgm
GROUP BY p.id
```

And that work as expected, but now i want to know the `MAX` of `AVG(note)` and of `COUNT(note)`, But if i do `MAX(COUNT(note))` it return me an error : `Invalid use of group function`. I understand why there is this problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

The only way I see, is to do two subrequest and put it inside `MAX()`, but is there a better way than two subrequest ?

(I'm on MySql with php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpliest answer would be,

```
SELECT  p.id, name, AVG(note), COUNT(note) totalCount
FROM    notes n
        INNER JOIN prgm p
            ON p.id=n.id_prgm
GROUP   BY p.id
ORDER   BY totalCount DESC
LIMIT   1
```

but the disadvantage is that it does not care for duplicate record having the highest count. The alternative is,

```
SELECT  p.id, name, AVG(note), COUNT(note)
FROM    notes n
        INNER JOIN prgm p
            ON p.id=n.id_prgm
GROUP   BY p.id
HAVING  COUNT(note) =
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT COUNT(note) totalCount
            FROM    notes n
                    INNER JOIN prgm p
                        ON p.id=n.id_prgm
            GROUP   BY p.id 
            ORDER   BY totalCount DESC
            LIMIT   1
        )
```

Comment: the duplicate record problem is not one here, because i just need theses MAX, not other info. The goal is to use theses max in a formula in the query that i give. But maybe I can do your first query, get the MAX values in a php var and use it in a second query to get all prgm infos ? I prefear to do only one query, but if there is no better way, I will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for either column with an `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT p.id, name, AVG(note), COUNT(note)
FROM notes n
    JOIN prgm p
    ON p.id=n.id_prgm
GROUP BY p.id
order by avg(note) desc
limit 1
```

To do both at the same time, requires some subqueries.  I would do it thusly:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.avgnote, t.countnote
from (select max(avgnote) as maxavg, max(countnote) as maxcount
      from (SELECT p.id, name, AVG(note) as avgnote, COUNT(note) as countnote
            FROM notes n
                 JOIN prgm p
                 ON p.id=n.id_prgm
            GROUP BY p.id
           ) t
     ) themax join
     (SELECT p.id, name, AVG(note) as avgnote, COUNT(note) as countnote
      FROM notes n
           JOIN prgm p
           ON p.id=n.id_prgm
      GROUP BY p.id
     ) t
     on t.avgnote = themax.avgnote or t.countnote = themax.countnote
```

Comment: As i explain in my comment to JW 웃, my goal is to use theses max in a formula in the query that i give. And i'm not sure to have understand your second query : it goal is to give me the list of all prgm with max, right ? so it's not what i search for because I only need theses MAX. But i can use your first query, get the MAX values in a php var and use it in a second query to get all prgm infos ? I prefear to do only one query, but if there is no better. (Maybe i bad explain, because you both didn't understand really what i would, sorry for that) and thank.

Answer (score 0):

This is your database with some testdata (compatible with Access, MySQL and Oracle):

```
CREATE TABLE notes (
  id int NOT NULL,
  note int NOT NULL,
  id_prgm int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO notes (id, note, id_prgm) VALUES (1, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO notes (id, note, id_prgm) VALUES (3, 16, 1);
INSERT INTO notes (id, note, id_prgm) VALUES (4, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO notes (id, note, id_prgm) VALUES (5, 4, 2);
INSERT INTO notes (id, note, id_prgm) VALUES (6, 5, 2);

ALTER TABLE notes
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE TABLE prgm (
  id int NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO prgm (id, name) VALUES (0, 'program 1');
INSERT INTO prgm (id, name) VALUES (1, 'program 1');
INSERT INTO prgm (id, name) VALUES (2, 'program 2');

ALTER TABLE prgm
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Your query:

```
SELECT p.id, name, AVG(note), COUNT(note)
FROM notes n
    JOIN prgm p
    ON p.id=n.id_prgm
GROUP BY p.id
```

returns these records:

```
id  name        AVG(note)   COUNT(note)     
1   program 1   10.0000     2
2   program 2   4.0000      3
```

If you only want the MAX of the AVG and COUNT column use this query:

```
select max(avg_note), max(count_note)
from (
  SELECT AVG(note) as avg_note, COUNT(note) as count_note
  FROM notes n, prgm p 
  WHERE p.id=n.id_prgm
  GROUP BY p.id
) temptable
```

This query is not also compatible with MySQL but also with Access and Oracle because I changed  JOIN  ON .. in FROM table1, table2 WHERE ..
And I removed the *name* field in the SELECT which was not included in the GROUP BY.

I also removed the unnecessary field *p.id* in SELECT because of performance/memory reasons.

Query will return:

```
max(avg_note)   max(count_note)     
10.0000         3
```